# Не обновлять таблицу MySql если изображение не выбрано

Tags: mysql, sql

столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Сохранил в бд текст и фото, если я хочу отредактировать только текст, а фото не выбрал то при сохранении в базу попадает null. А как решить не знаю(

Вот запрос к базе

```
$query = "UPDATE $table SET image='".$_FILES['test_image']['name']."', message='".$_POST["test_mess"]." ' WHERE id=".$_POST["update"];
```

Вот код отвечающий за загрузку фотки

```
/* Соединяемся с базой данных */
$hostname = "localhost"; // название/путь сервера, с MySQL
$username = "root"; // имя пользователя (в Denwer`е по умолчанию "root")
$password = ""; // пароль пользователя (в Denwer`е по умолчанию пароль     отсутствует, этот параметр можно оставить пустым)
$dbName = "namebd"; // название базы данных

/* Таблица MySQL, в которой будут храниться данные */
$table = "test_table";

/* Создаем соединение */
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Не могу создать     соединение");

/* Выбираем базу данных. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее */
mysql_select_db($dbName) or die (mysql_error());

/* Определяем текущую дату */
$cdate = date("Y-m-d");

/* Составляем запрос для вставки информации в таблицу*/
$query = "UPDATE $table SET image='".$_FILES['test_image']['name']."',     message='".$_POST["test_mess"]." ' WHERE id=".$_POST["update"];



/* Выполняем запрос. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее. */
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

/* Закрываем соединение */
mysql_close();

/* В случае успешного сохранения выводим сообщение и ссылку возврата */
echo ("<div style=\"text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;\">
<font color=\"green\">Данные успешно сохранены!</font>

<a href=\"view_data.php\">Вернутся назад</a></div>");

//Загрузка файлов
if($_FILES['test_image']['type']=="image/jpeg")
{
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['test_image']['tmp_name']));
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['test_image']['tmp_name'],"./img/".$_FILES['test_image']['name']);
echo "фото загружено и данные обновлены<br>";
echo "<img src='img/".$_FILES['test_image']['name']."' width='200'>";
}

}
```

Подскажите, как исправить, и какие файлы скинуть?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `if ($_FILES['test_image']['name']) { логика }`. Это было так сложно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно было бы ограничиться комментарием с указанием ссылки на функцию [COALESCE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce), но т.к. от кода попахивает "Женей Поповым", решил немного расширить ответ.

```
<?php
/*
Данные, получаемые от клиента, крайне желательно обрабатывать,
а не подставлять сразу в запрос
*/
$data = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, [
    'test_mess' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'update' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT
]);


/*
(*) дело ваше, но я бы переименовывал файлы уникальными именами, 
т.к. при совпадении, новый будет перезаписывать предыдущий с таким же именем
*/ 
$image = null;
if ($_FILES['test_image']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK &&
    (new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE))->file($_FILES['test_image']['tmp_name']) == 'image/jpeg' &&
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['test_image']['tmp_name'], './img/' . $_FILES['test_image']['name'])
   ) {
    $image = $_FILES['test_image']['name'];
}

/*
Если уж и используете переменную с именем таблицы, что лично я не приветствую,
то хотя бы оборачивайте её, да и вообще все имена полей и таблиц, в "грависы" (обратные кавычки)
*/
$query = "UPDATE `$table` SET `image` = COALESCE(?, `image`), `message` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";

/*
Судя по вашему коду, вангую, что вы используете старое расширения mysql_*.
Рекомендуется использовать MySQLi или PDO.
Т.к. я работую с PDO, пример ниже основан на его синтаксисе
MY_DB_NAME - имя БД
MY_USERNAME - пользователь
MY_PASSWORD - пароль
*/
$dbh = new \PDO('mysql:dbname=MY_DB_NAME;host=127.0.0.1', 'MY_USERNAME', 'MY_PASSWORD');
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute([
    $image,
    $data['test_mess'],
    $data['update']
]);
```

Пригодится:

1. [Фильтрация данных](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.filter.php)
2. [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) или [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php) на ваш выбор, если вы всё еще их не используете
3. Для общего понимания - [SQL injection](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0), хотя тема гораздо обширней
4. п.2 + п.3 подводят к подготавливаемым запросам [для MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) или [для PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php), в зависимости от вашего выбора. Не игнорируйте данные возможности, т.к. они хоть и не дают стопроцентной гарантии, но значительно повышают уровень защиты.

P.S. Код выше - это не образец для подражания, а руководство к действию! Поэтому **не нужно бездумно его копипастить**, но разобраться и понять суть - желательно.

Comment: Deonis, я явно не вижу очевидного, пытался сделать по вашему примеру, картинка загружается, но данные в таблицу не попадают, ни сообщения ни имя картинки... Я отредактировал первое сообщение, там полный код файла, гляньте пожалуйста.

Comment: @MichaelCoates, Включите [вывод всех ошибок](http://phpfaq.ru/debug), проверьте названия полей и их типы. В комментарии к строке запроса, вы пишите: "*для вставки информации*", но запрос у вас на обновление, а не на вставку. Вы точно ничего не перепутали?

Comment: Deonis вы правы, я вообще не туда смотрел, сейчас все работает, спасибо что ткнули носом, а то бы я сам сума сошел бы)) Хорошего вам дня ;)